# Find the least order differential equation that accepts $y=a\cos{(\ln{x})}+b\sin{(\ln{x})}$ general solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

There are two coefficients but I found the least order differential equation as first order one. When I put the given general solution to the differential equation that I found, It provides the equation.

Here's how I found the differential equation:

$$y=a\cos{(\ln{x})}+b\sin{(\ln{x})} \Rightarrow y\prime=-\frac{a}{x}\sin{(\ln{x})}+\frac{b}{x}\cos{(\ln{x})}$$

Multiply both sides with $\frac{ax}{b}$,

$$\frac{ax}{b}y\prime=-\frac{a^2}{b}\sin{(\ln{x})}+a\cos{(\ln{x})}$$

$$a\cos{(\ln{x})}=y-b\sin{(\ln{x})}\Rightarrow\frac{ax}{b}y\prime=-\frac{a^2}{b}\sin{(\ln{x})}+y-b\sin{(\ln{x})}$$

$$\frac{ax}{b}y\prime=y-\left(\frac{a^2+b^2}{b}\right)\sin{(\ln{x})}$$

Multiply both sides with $\frac{b}{ax}$ to simplify,

$$y\prime=\frac{b}{ax}y-\frac{a^2+b^2}{ax}\sin{(\ln{x})}$$

$$y\prime-\frac{b}{ax}y=-\frac{a^2+b^2}{ax}\sin{(\ln{x})}$$

The last formula is the first order differential equation that I found. When I put the given solution and it's derivative, it provides the eqution. Is my solution correct? Or should have I found second order differential equation for some reason, because there are 2 coefficients, a and b?

Comment: From what I understand, $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary constants, so your ODE should be independent of $a,b$ (and indeed should be of order 2).

Comment: I think the second interpretation is the good one. The wording of the question is clear: $a$ and $b$ are not considered as "a priori" given.

Comment: @projectilemotion Hmm, okay. This question was asked on my midterm exam on differential equations course at school. My lecturer shared the solution and the solution has 2nd order diff. equation. But I have a question. then why my equation which is 1st order provides the solution?

Comment: @JeanMarie Okay, I understand. Can you check the other comment here that I just shared, please? Thanks.

Comment: You have to eliminate a and b. The first order differential equation you have arrived at contains the constants a and b. The given equation itself can be considered as zero order D E. That's not what we want. We want a DE without the constants which is the solution.

Comment: @ICCQBE see my answer to your questionning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to eliminate both constants $a$ and $b$. Better to rewrite the solution as :
$$y=a\cos{(\ln{x})}+b\sin{(\ln{x})}$$
$$y=a\cos{(t)}+b\sin{(t)}$$
With $x=e^t$.

Then the characteristic polynomial is
$$r^2+1=0$$
And the DE is:
$$y''(t)+y(t)=0$$
And
$$\dfrac {dy}{dt}=\dfrac {dy}{dx}\dfrac {dx}{dt}=x\dfrac {dy}{dx}$$
$$\dfrac {d^2y}{dt^2}=x\dfrac {d}{dx} \left (x\dfrac {dy}{dx} \right)=......$$
The differential equation becomes:
$$x^2y''+xy'+y=0$$

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer the question you address as a comment:

Let us work somehow backwards. If, in your first degree equation

$$y^\prime-\frac{b}{ax}y=-\frac{a^2+b^2}{ax}\sin{(\ln{x})}\tag{1}$$

you plug

$$y=A\cos{(\ln{x})}+B\sin{(\ln{x})}\tag{2}$$

(please note that I have taken variables capital $A,B$):

$$-A\sin{(\ln{x})}+B\cos{(\ln{x})}\dfrac{1}{x}-(A\cos{(\ln{x})}+B\sin{(\ln{x})})\frac{b}{ax}=-\frac{a^2+b^2}{ax}\sin{(\ln{x})}$$

otherwise said:

$$-aA\sin{(\ln{x})}+aB\cos{(\ln{x})}-bA\cos{(\ln{x})}-bB\sin{(\ln{x})}=-(a^2+b^2)\sin{(\ln{x})}$$

You see that, identifying the LHS and the RHS:

$$aA+bB=-(a^2+b^2)  \ \ \text{and} \ \ aB-bA=0$$

a linear system whose solutions are $A=a$ and $B=b$.

It is in this particular case

Therefore a possible answer to your question is that the set of functions (2) is the solution of the whole **family** of differential equations (1), for all possible $a,b$.